# Windows programming: setting different icons for the different file types handled by your application

Tags: c#, windows, registry

How do you go about setting different icons for the different file types handled by your application in Microsoft Windows?

Even just a high-level explanation will help.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most file associations are defined under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. In There, you define a class for each file extension. For example, under `HKCR\.txt` you'll find `txtfile` as the default value. If you go to `HKCR\txtfile`, you'll find all the actions associated with this class, including `open` under `HKCR\txtfile\shell` and the icon under `HKCR\txtfile\DefaultIcon`.

MSDN has some [more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144158%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

File extensions and their icons are controlled through the registry

Here's some more info on how to do it with a deployment project, most installers like installshield that's included for free have similar features

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/customfiletype12082006000848am/customfiletype.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assign the icons to the files in Windows registry. You can give icons in a dll just like Windows' shell32.dll.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio

Microsoft use a trick to handle this situation.

he make a dll and he put all icon on them. in system registry he make the rule that how they show the icon for ascx and aspx.
he put the file extension as name and icon as value.

when visual studio run visual studio read the system registry and show the icon.

if you don't believe this you can read this in your regedit if you have visual studio in your system.

Comment: I though Visual studio was a 'she' :)

Comment: i used it for developer who use this trick to develop the system not for visual studio.